# For nested loop vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
   .cells(2,1).value=NewArr(0)
  .cells(2,2).value=NewArr(1)
  .cells(2,3).value=NewArr(2)
  .cells(2,4).value=NewArr(3)
  .cells(3,1).value=NewArr(4)
  .cells(3,2).value=NewArr(5)
  .cells(3,3).value=NewArr(6)
  .cells(3,4).value=NewArr(7)
 .cells(4,1).value=NewArr(8)
 .cells(4,2).value=NewArr(9)
 .cells(4,3).value=NewArr(10)
 .cells(4,4).value=NewArr(11)
```

I am new to programming. Can any one help me put this in a For nested loop? I will 
   greatful if any one would help solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
dim i as integer, j as integer, n as integer

n = 0

for i = 2 to 4
    for j = 1 to 4
        .cells(i, j).value=NewArr(n)
        n = n + 1
    next j
next i
```

Comment: @user7054740 Glad to hear that, please would you mark this as answer, thank you!